# ZooKeeper error ; unrecognized host name for local configuration

Tags: hadoop, zookeeper

I am using Kylin 4+ and want to use Windows and run it locally (without Hadoop).
I follow this tut in their website which states that zookeeper config must be set to local like so:

```
kylin.env.zookeeper-is-local=true
```

Which supposes that Kylin won't read any other parameter (as connection string) to connect.
But when I run Kylin I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: sandbox.hortonworks.com
```

on load table from csv in the model tab.
When I check the configuration from within the Web UI I have the following configuration for zooKeeper:

```
kylin.env.zookeeper-is-local=true
kylin.env.zookeeper-connect-string=sandbox.hortonworks.com
```

But from the \kylin\examples\test_case_data\sandbox\kylin.properties:

I have commented out kylin.env.zookeeper-connect-string=sandbox.hortonworks.com

How to solve this and pass by ZooKeeper?